# ActiveRecord Joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Ok, so, if I do a `User.joins(:session_users)`, I only get the attributes of users table.

How do I get the attributes of both tables in ActiveRecord way, i.e., not SQL?

**EDIT ONE**

Ok, based on the first answer, I'm trying to have it displayed.

So, this is the method written in Users Controller

```
def blah 
  @users = User.includes(:session_users)
    @users.each do |user|
      user.session_users
    end
end
```

Then I have this in the users view `blah.html.erb`

```
 <%= @users.session_users %>
```

And this in the routing section:

```
  match "/users/blah" => "users#blah"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `includes` instead of `joins`. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins for more info. This should fetch columns for both,

```
users = User.includes(:session_users)
users.each do |user|
  user.session_users
end
```

Note, this still performs 2 SQL queries.

**Edit**

Updated answer assumes that a `user` `has_many :session_users`

Routes:

```
# config/routes.rb

get '/users/blah' => 'users#blah'
```

Controller:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def blah
    @users = User.includes(:session_users)
  end
end
```

View:

```
# app/views/users/blah.html.erb

<% @users.each do |user| %>

  <%= user.name %> // assumes user has a name attribute

  <% user.session_users.each do |session_user| %>
    <%= session_user.attributes %> // prints all the attributes
    <%= session_user.created_at %> // assumes the user has a created_at attribute
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: when I tried the includes in the console, it doesn't show the attributes of the session_users table. (yeah, I know it performs SQL behind the scenes - just wanted to know the ActiveRecord way).

Comment: What is your query in the console? I've updated my code sample to show how you would access the `user`'s `session_users`.

Comment: well, initially it was the original as written in my post. I tried your code sample in my console, and I still get only user's table attributes.

Comment: @user2730725 that's not possible because that doesn't make any sense. What you will do with the mixture of both attributes ? The above solution (`joins/includes`) serves all needs. When you do `user.session_users`, you are not performing any sql query,data is coming from memory .

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar, ok. Going to add a bit more to my post because I'm having trouble having the results being displayed, and I think I'm doing something wrong. Please let me know what. Sam is right I think, but I can't figure it how to have it displayed.

Comment: @Sam, I get this error when I try to display the page `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` and it's referring to this line: `<% @users.each do |user| %>`

Comment: Try changing that line to `<% User.includes(:session_users).each do |user| %>` instead.

Comment: @Sam, it works, albeit messily since it's just a page of data. But I'll figure out how to have it displayed nicely. Thank you, Sam. If you don't mind me asking one more question, why did I have to include the User model in the view page (ie, referring to your last comment. Why didn't it work with just `@users`?

Comment: I don't think the view was able to get the `@users` instance variable from the controller action so I bypassed the controller action and talked directly to the model. Not best practice. You'll want to try and figure out why the view can't see the `@users` instance variable.

Comment: I've updated the code snippets to include the controller class and routes I would expect to work.

Comment: @Sam, thanks. Appreciate it. Went through over everything to see if I could get it to work without having to bypass controller action, and it still generates that error. Hm. Either way, I'll figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sam, just wanted to let you know that I finally got it working without having to bypass the controller action. It was my fault, I had the `def blah` method inside another method by accident. That's why view couldn't see it. Still, it was interesting that I could write User inside view. I know it's not best practice, but it was interesting! So, thanks for letting me know about that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to add fields from a joined table to the yielded objects, you can add `select`:

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN stolen_passwords
                    ON users.social_security_number=stolen_passwords.ssn")
    .select("*").find_each do |user|
      logger.debug { 
        "A #{user.full_name} has a password hash #{user.password_hash}" 
      }
end
```

Here imaginary `user.full_name` is an instance method of `User` and `user.password_hash` comes from the `stolen_passwords` table. You could also limit the queried/returned fields by listing them in the call to `select` explicitly.

We sometimes use this in rake tasks that enrich the database from or compare it against third party data sources: we would join our tables with provided tables and generate a 'side-by-side' CSV with columns from both. Plain SQL would work just as well, but going via active record often allows to reuse familiar scopes, or methods that perform calculations in ruby.

## Caveat

Unfortunately the fields coming from the joined tables will not be cast to appropriate ruby types, they will all be strings (which is especially logical if using SQL string for the `joins`). But it is easy to cast the joined attributes with something like:

```
module CastJoinedColumns
  def cast_joined_columns joined_record
    columns_hash.each do |column_name, column|
      if joined_record.attributes.include?(column_name)
        joined_record[column_name] = column.type_cast(joined_record[column_name])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This module is meant to be `extended` into a model appearing on the right side of the join and the method be called with a joined record. It might misbehave and should be improved for the cases where the same column name appears in multiple tables, but is an ok starting point (works perfectly for us with third party data sources using column names guaranteed not to clash with our own).